# Use a function inside a function from another .c file?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to change the size of the array from another function. The code compiles but the program crashes... I am stuck, very stuck. New to this, my head is spinning up down left right aaaaah........

**array.c**

```
struct array {
    int* data;
    int size;
};

struct array* array_create()
{
    struct array* array = (struct array*) malloc(sizeof(struct array));
    array->data = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 10000);
    array->size = 10000;
    return array;
}

void array_resize(struct array* array, int size)
{
    if (size > array->size) {
        free(array);
        array->data = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    }

    array->size = size;
}

int array_size(struct array* array)
{
    return array->size;
}
```

**array.h**

```
typedef struct array* ARRAY;

ARRAY array_create();
void array_resize(struct array* array, int size);
```

**edit.c**

```
void edit()
{
    array_resize(array, 100); // I can run the code but program crashes
}
```

**main.c**

```
ARRAY array;
array = array_create();
edit();                       // Program crashes
```

Comment: You need to learn how to **use a debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: Is there any alternatives to gdb for windows?

Comment: Read the documentation of your compiler.

Comment: Btw, [do not cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Its a good practice after freeing something like `array` to set it to `NULL`. You catch errors easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
    free(array);
    array->data = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
```

Here you free `array`, and dereference it at the *next line*. That's undefined behavior. But seems to be the cause of your crash.

Comment: But if I type `array_resize(array, 100)` in main.c instead of in edit.c it will work perfectly!

Comment: @user3285214, that's the nature of *undefined behavior*, you can't predict how it will act.

Comment: I tried putting `free(array)` under the other line of code but the program still crashes...

Comment: @user3285214, you shouldn't ever access memory you freed, directly or in other scopr. You probably meant to free `array->data`

Comment: It still crashes... But actually the function array_resize() is pre coded and should not be changed...

Comment: @user3285214, than seek out whomever pre-coded it and punch them in the face.

Comment: Ok, well I have tried `free(array->data)` and `free(array)` but both still gives me the crash. I have also tried switching place on the two lines of code you quoted.

Comment: @user3285214, without seeing exactly what you did I can't tell you where the error is hiding. I suggest you set to `NULL` any memory you free and use debugger to look for freed-memory access. If all is well on that front, your error is not in the code you showed us.

Comment: I edited the OP, added a function in array.c. The program crashes if I (in edit() in edit.c) call `array_size(array)`. For the love of god , I don't understand why!?!?!?!

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
void array_resize(struct array* array, int size)
{
    if (size > array->size) {
        free(array);
        array->data = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    }

    array->size = size;
}
```

Should be `free(array->data)` not `free(array)`. Or better `realloc` `array->data`.

Also, unless you are looking for trouble, declare your functions in your `.h` files as you do in your `.c` files, i.e.:

```
struct array;
struct array *array_create();
```

and include `array.h` from `array.c`.

Comment: Crashes where and how? Compile it with `-Wall` and fix all the warnings. Run it under `gdb` and see where it crashes. Run it under `valgrind`. If you are still stuck, post back the exact code you are running in a compilable state.